# Identical particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If the wave function of a system of identical fermions is totally antisymmetric then can you understand me that how can be electron,proton,neutron all fermions are distinguishable particle?

Comment: As @noah mentioned, the key is that only identical particles are indistinguishable. You might see this in contrast to classical mechanics where even identical particles can be distinguished as all of them have well-defined trajectories and you can track which one went where. The loss of the existence of a notion of trajectory for quantum particles makes identical particles inevitably indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the word *identical*. They are only indistinguishable if they are the same kind of particle. Therefore, the wave function is only antisymmetric under exchange of identical particles, you can't just exchange an electron for a proton, as this would completely change the physics of the setup.

Comment: If the operator were not symmetric under particle interchange,the particle would be distinguishable.what is the physical significance of symmetric and antisymmetric operator

Comment: Well, the fact is that an electron and a proton *are* distinguishable. Don't you agree?

Comment: Superb sir you are mind blowing i am now understand  thanku very much